# Installing RnBeads via bioconductor - .onLoad failed in loadNamespace(), call: NULL

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to install `RnBeads` from bioconductor but the installation of its dependancy `TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene` fails. The error is:

```
biocLite("RnBeads")
BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), R 3.4.3 (2017-11-30).
Installing package(s) ‘RnBeads’
also installing the dependencies ‘FDb.InfiniumMethylation.hg19’, ‘methylumi’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/data/annotation/src/contrib/FDb.InfiniumMethylation.hg19_2.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 38996322 bytes (37.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 37.2 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib/methylumi_2.24.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6178909 bytes (5.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.9 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib/RnBeads_1.10.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6437974 bytes (6.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 6.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘FDb.InfiniumMethylation.hg19’ ...
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene', details:
  call: NULL
  error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error : package ‘TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene’ could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘FDb.InfiniumMethylation.hg19’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpY8Yf4l/downloaded_packages’
installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: doMC, doSNOW,
  foreach, iterators, snow, boot, class, cluster, codetools, foreign,
  KernSmooth, lattice, MASS, Matrix, mgcv, nlme, nnet, rpart, spatial, survival
```

As suggested by the error message, I tried setting `options(expressions=500000)`, which unfortunately did not change the error message. An important note may be that I am under network mount and don't have administrative access rights.

**Edit**

I don't have a .Rprofile file.

Note about `installation path not writeable`:
Typing .libPaths() reveals that my home R folder is at the first position (and it is writable). The other paths (`"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"`                          , `"/usr/lib/R/site-library"` and `"/usr/lib/R/library"`) are not writable without sudo.

I also tried to delete my home R folder and to reinstall it. The reinstallation of all packages worked for all packages except for the three listed above (same error message). I also tried `biocLite("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene", lib.loc=.libPaths()[1], lib=.libPaths()[1])` to specifically address my home R directory, but the same error is showing up (but without the `installation path not writeable` part).

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocInstaller_1.28.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It  might be better then to raise the error to support.bioconductor.org to let the maintainers know about it.

Comment: Ok, I will do. If the error is fixable from user side, I will report the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reported the [error on support.bioconductor.org](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/104488/) but we were not able to solve the problem. It seems that some dependencies are making problems, but as reinstalling my home R folder did not resolve the issue, I have come up with the following workaround:

I downloaded the latest R version from my favorite CRAN mirror, opened an R session with `pathToNewR/bin/R` from my terminal and installed `RnBeads` there. This works fine.

Note: I had to make sure that `pathToNewR/library` is the only entry in `.libPaths()`, as per default, my home R folder was also contained in `.libPaths()`.

As a consequence, I am independent from the (maybe broken) R version and packages on my server and can finally work with `RnBeads` :)

Comment: If I come up with another solution that works fine with my server R version, I will post an update here.